# Loop xml and store values as variables - C#

Tags: c#

New to C# here and I would like some help with a small project of mine. I have an XML file with elements that I would like to loop through and store it´s values and use.

I want to grab all of the descending attributes in "week 2" and store them as variables and execute some code. Than I would like to do the process all over again with the next descending elements of the next element "week 2".

Can any help me out?

My C# code so far:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(IHCSchedulingConfigFile);

var xelem = xdoc.Descendants("week")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("weeknumber").Value.Equals("2"))
                .ToList();

foreach (var week in xelem)
{
    int groupNumber = Convert.ToInt32(xelem.Elements("groupNumber").Any());
    string starTtime = xelem.Elements("starttime").ToString();
    int startDay = Convert.ToInt32(xelem.Elements("startday").Any());
    string endTime = xelem.Elements("endtime").ToString();
    int endDay = Convert.ToInt32(xelem.Elements("endday").Any());

    Console.WriteLine(groupNumber);
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
    Console.WriteLine(starTtime);
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
    Console.WriteLine(startDay);
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
    Console.WriteLine(endTime);
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
    Console.WriteLine(endDay);
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

    Console.ReadLine();

    // Execute code 
}
```

XML to read values from:

```
<root>
    <week weeknumber="1">
        <groupNumber>1</groupNumber>
        <starttime>10:00</starttime>
        <startday>8</startday>
        <endtime>12:00</endtime>
        <endday>8</endday>
    </week> 
    <week weeknumber="1">
        <groupNumber>2</groupNumber>
        <starttime>10:00</starttime>
        <startday>8</startday>
        <endtime>12:00</endtime>
        <endday>8</endday>
    </week>
    <week weeknumber="2">
        <groupNumber>1</groupNumber>
        <starttime>10:00</starttime>
        <startday>8</startday>
        <endtime>12:00</endtime>
        <endday>8</endday>
    </week> 
    <week weeknumber="2">
        <groupNumber>2</groupNumber>
        <starttime>10:00</starttime>
        <startday>8</startday>
        <endtime>12:00</endtime>
        <endday>8</endday>
    </week>
    <week weeknumber="3">
        <groupNumber>1</groupNumber>
        <starttime>10:00</starttime>
        <startday>8</startday>
        <endtime>12:00</endtime>
        <endday>8</endday>
    </week> 
    <week weeknumber="3">
        <groupNumber>2</groupNumber>
        <starttime>10:00</starttime>
        <startday>8</startday>
        <endtime>12:00</endtime>
        <endday>8</endday>
    </week>
</root>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: Using `ToString()` will give you the object type in this case. You should try `.FirstOrDefault().Value` as `Any()` is just giving the integer value of the boolean it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also convert to object and loop

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load($"XMLFile1.xml");

var items = xdoc.Descendants("week")
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("weeknumber").Value == "2")
                .Select(xelem => new
                        {
                            groupNumber = xelem.Element("groupNumber").Value,
                            starTtime = xelem.Element("starttime").Value,
                            startDay = Convert.ToInt32(xelem.Element("startday").Value),
                            endTime = xelem.Element("endtime").Value,
                            endDay = Convert.ToInt32(xelem.Element("endday").Value)
                        });

foreach (var item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.groupNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your for each loop. You are not currently getting the values, you are using  `Any()` which is returning the integer value of the boolean this method returns.

```
foreach (var week in xelem)
{
    int groupNumber = Convert.ToInt32(week.Elements("groupNumber").FirstOrDefault().Value);
    string startTime = week.Elements("starttime").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    int startDay = Convert.ToInt32(week.Elements("startday").FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
    string endTime = week.Elements("endtime").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    int endDay = Convert.ToInt32(week.Elements("endday").FirstOrDefault().Value);

    Console.WriteLine(groupNumber);
    Console.WriteLine(startTime);
    Console.WriteLine(startDay);
    Console.WriteLine(endTime);
    Console.WriteLine(endDay);
    Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
}
```

Doing this you may also wish to add checks for null, unless you can guarantee the XML will have these present. One way you could do this is using the `?` operator.

```
int startDay = Convert.ToInt32(xelem.Elements("startday").FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan! 

This kinda works. I get values but I get the same values twice.

the code loops through the first element twice so I get the same values.

Comment: Please see updated answer. You were using `xelem` instead of `week` within the for loop. So it was always picking up the first entry as opposed to the current iteration.